# What is the difference between CIL and MSIL (IL)?

Tags: .net

Are these two terms interchangeable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

CIL is the term used in the [CLI Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm). MSIL is (I suppose) CIL created by MS tools. Effectively they are synonymous.

[Brad Abrams says this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/09/20/CILorMSIL.aspx)

Answer (score 22):

MSIL was the original name, but when it was turned into a standard it was renamed CIL.

Answer (score 5):

Both the terms are similar but with following difference:

CIL –  Common Intermediate Language  – is the term used in the International Standard.

MSIL –  Microsoft Intermediate Language   – is the product term for the Microsoft implementation of that standard.